# Sql Query to find reporting user details

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

i have a table with follow fields

---

**UserID**    ***UserName***          **ReportingUserID**

---

```
 1   Vinoth          Null
 2   Kumar            1
 3   Raja             1
 4   Ragu             2
 5   Vignesh          2
 6   Yoga             3
 7   Yogesh           2
 8   Eswar            4
 9   Esakki           3
 .   ...              .
```

### .   ....             .

if i gave UserID as 1 then a query will display all users reporting to him will be displayed

if i gave USeRID as 1

Then result will be

---

**UserID**    ***UserName***          **ReportingUserID**

---

```
 2   Kumar            1
 3   Raja             1
 4   Ragu             2
 5   Vignesh          2
 6   Yoga             3
 7   Yogesh           2
 8   Eswar            4
 9   Esakki           3
 .   ...              .
```

### .   ....             .

Comment: Actually what is your question?

Comment: I am curious what you want? if you want it displayed as rows, you can simply `SELECT UserId, UserName FROM yourTable WHERE ReportingUserID = 1` ... if you wanted it as columns, then you will most likely need to look at pivoting data

Comment: @PandiyanCool: 
If UserID=1
He has 2 Reportee that two user have their reportees.

If we enter UserID as 1 it will display all reportees under him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using a recursive [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a
>   CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in
>   the same query.

Something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
UserID INT, 
UserName VARCHAR(20),
ReportingUserID INT
)


INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1,'Vinoth',Null),
(2,'Kumar',1),
(3,'Raja',1),
(4,'Ragu',2),
(5,'Vignesh',2),
(6,'Yoga',3),
(7,'Yogesh',2),
(8,'Eswar',4),
(9,'Esakki',3)

DECLARE @UserID INT = 1

;WITH ReportingUsers AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @Table
        WHERE   ReportingUserID = @UserID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
                ReportingUsers ru   ON  ru.UserID = t.ReportingUserID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    ReportingUsers
```

Comment: Thank you @astander i got my result.

Comment: if a user does not have reportee means the above query return following error " The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
 "

Please help me to handle this error